# REACT - conditional switch render, pattern to be identified

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just saw this excellent way of doing a switch by passing an object as a `call`? or `apply`? to another object. Does this pattern have a name in normal Javascript? I'd like to read up on it, so I can better understand how it works in React:

```
this.state = {
    nav: content1,
}

render() {
    return (
        <section>
            {{
                content1: <content1 />,
                content2: <content2 />,
                content3: <content3 />,
            }[this.state.nav]}
        </section>
    );
}
```

Comment: That *is* normal Javascript. It's just accessing the property straight away, without you having to create the object first, THEN access it. So rather than `let obj={...}; let val=obj[key];` you can just use the key on the raw object straight away: `let val={...}[key];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the `JSX` is considered like `JSON` objects surrounded by curly braces {}.

Keys and values are separated by a colon.
    You can access the object values by using dot (.) notation:

```
myObj = { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null };
x = myObj.name;

You can also access the object values by using bracket ([]) notation:
myObj = { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null };
x = myObj["name"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation. (face => palm) I can see it now. JSX messes with my head sometimes!!

Answer (score 1):

This is simply an object inside of JSX.

```
{{
   content1: <content1 />,
   content2: <content2 />,
   content3: <content3 />,
}[this.state.nav]}
```

Is the same as

```
{favSnack: “Apple”}[‘favSnack’]
```

Comment: Make sure to use straight quotes rather than so-called smart quotes.